# Kentico 11 - Email marketing CMS display issues on hosted environments

Tags: kentico, email, email-templates

I'm trying to implement an email marketing email using a few widgets that gets triggers on submission of a form. Everything has been built and works locally but having issues with the CMS once uploaded to any hosted environment ('CI' and 'UAT' as we call them).

From what I can see everything has been sent up correctly but when editing templates there seem to be some CMS styling issues from some of the iframe loaded elements.

Have attached a screen grab as an example.
There are no console errors and no errors in the Kentico logs so I'm a bit stumped as to what is causing this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Luke

[image]

Comment: Have you tried viewing it in other browsers, or disabling any adblockers/extensions that might interfere?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue. We had recently upgraded from a previous version of Kentico and the associated updated stylesheets hadn't been uploaded to the development environments so were missing styles in these new areas of the CMS